# Using lodash and trying to update and Object with multiple objects. (editing items)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I am using lodash and redux/react to make a simple app. Right now I have it returning an object with multiple objects in it. So it looks something like this when I get the final object.

Object { 2: Object, 34: Object}

Each Object has a title , id, and description. I used lodash to mapKeys and make each object within the single object to be keyed with the ID. This way it is easier to find each object. For example Mainobject[34] will return that object even though it is second in the Object.

So this is all working well now and I want to be able to update the object or edit some code and replace one of the excising objects. I am using redux/react so understanding of that will be required to understand what I am trying to do.

As you can see I am trying to use the _.get to find the item out of the mainObject and then update that particular item with the _.merge, I then am trying to use _.update, but in my console.log of my current state I am getting this in the console:

*current state is: -> Object {2: Object, 34: Object}*

*current state is: -> Object {2: Object, 34: Object, object Object: undefined}*

The second console has the object with the id of 34 and everything is updated and working correctly, but I am getting the undefind object Object at the end.

Here is my reducer:

```
const reducer = function(state={}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "POST_BOOK":
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'id');
    break;
    case "DELETE_BOOK":
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    break;
    case "UPDATE_BOOK":
      let foundItem = _.get(state, action.payload.id);
      let updateItem = _.merge(state[action.payload.id],foundItem,action.payload);
      console.log(updateItem);
      return _.update(state, state[action.payload.id], updateItem);
    break;
  }
  return state
}
```

Here are my actions:

```
store.dispatch({
  type: "POST_BOOK",
  payload: [
  {
    id: 34,
    title: 'this is the book title',
    description: 'this is the book description',
    price: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'this is the book title 2',
    description: 'this is the book description 2',
    price: 3.2
  }
]
});

// store.dispatch({
//   type: "DELETE_BOOK",
//   payload: 2
// });

store.dispatch({
  type: "UPDATE_BOOK",
  payload: {
    id: 34,
    title: 'this is book edit title',
    description: 'this is book edit edit',
    price: 2341.23
  }
})
```

Comment: The last parameter of `_.update` is supposed to be a function (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#update), here you pass it an object. This might be the problem I think

Comment: Is there a way to take the function and have it update the object that is selected?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you just need to `return updateItem` (and maybe rename it, I don't know). It seems to carry all the information you need, am I wrong?

Comment: Oh no, wait, it only has the updated item, sorry. But we are not so far from the solution. I might have an answer for you then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are very close to the solution here. The only thing wrong with your code is that `_.update` needs a function as third parameter while you are giving it an object.

Actually you can achieve what you want only with the `_.merge` method which recursively merges two objects.

So you just need to create an object that has the key of the item you want to update, and merge it with the previous state.

It'd look like this:

```
case "UPDATE_BOOK":
  let updates = {[action.payload.id]: action.payload};
  return _.merge(state, updates)
```

And this should do the trick (I have to admit I haven't tested the code)

Comment: Works just fine! is the updates just selecting the object with that id? I'm a little confused on how that works.

Comment: no, actually, the `updates` object represents all the keys you want to override in the state object. Here, with the example of the key `34`, we tell lodash to use the `state` as base and recursively override all the keys that are defined in the `updates` object. It is quite the same as `Object.assign` (except that it's recursive) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign